# Refactoring an expression that takes a block into method and its block argument

Tags: ruby, refactoring

```
a = (1..5).select(&:even?).map do |s|
  s * 2
end
a #=> [4, 8]
```

In Ruby, I would like to refactor `a`'s right hand side expression into a method and its block argument.

```
def refactor
  (1..5).select(&:even?).map { |e| yield e }
end

def refactor2(&block)
  (1..5).select(&:even?).map(&block)
end

b = refactor do |s|
  s * 2
end
b #=> [4, 8]
```

Using `refactor` or `refactor2`, I can get what I want.

But wrapping `yield` with block 
or back and forth between block and proc does not feel right to me.

Is there any more concise way?

Comment: It depends entirely on the use case. My gut says the method should return an enumerator (what if you want do something other than map it?), but I don't understand what the purpose is from your question alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require a block to be passed to the method, I would go with the second option. At least this way the parameter is in the method signature and it makes it more obvious that it is required.

Additionally I would raise `ArgumentError` if no block is provided:

```
def refactor(&block)
  raise ArgumentError.new("Block required") unless block

  (1..5).select(&:even?).map(&block)
end
```

Comment: I don't think this will raise an ArgumentError if no block is provided ... `def foo(&blk); [1].map(&blk); end; foo.to_a == [1]`

Comment: You are correct, the block argument can be `nil`. Silly mistake on my part. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that [Rails issue #30973](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/30973) and [Ruby issue #14045](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14045) answers my question.

According to [Ruby issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14045),

> There are no way to pass given blocks to other methods without using block parameters.

So there is no way other than `refactor` or `refactor2` and

```
back and forth between block and proc does not feel right to me.
```

this my concern was real with respect to performance.

[Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/30973) handles this performance problem by using `refactor` approach.